# Angular 4 and Angular Material long loading

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material2

Currently working on a portal https://scrawlless.com . I have an issue with long loading and not loading on some devices at all! Can you please check this web site? How can i reduce time of it's loading? It is powered by Angular 4, using Angular Material lib.

Why it can happen? It is not working at all on devices like Iphone 4, Lumia 520, 540 etc.
That is my app.module.ts file code:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthenticationService } from './_services/authentication.service';
import { SocketService } from './_services/socket.service';

import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/auth.guard';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MdNativeDateModule, MdDatepickerModule, MdButtonToggleModule, MdListModule, MdSnackBarModule, MdSelectModule, MdCheckboxModule, MdDialogModule, MdProgressSpinnerModule, MdInputModule, MdGridListModule, MdTooltipModule, MdSidenavModule, MdButtonModule, MdCardModule, MdMenuModule, MdToolbarModule, MdIconModule, MdTabsModule } from '@angular/material';

import { BodyComponent } from './_components/pages/body/body.component';
import { WorkspaceComponent } from './_components/pages/workspace/workspace.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './_components/pages/index/index.component';

import { UserDashboardComponent } from './_components/dashboards/user-dashboard/user-dashboard.component';
import { TeacherDashboardComponent } from './_components/dashboards/teacher-dashboard/teacher-dashboard.component';

import { UserSidebarComponent } from './_components/sidebars/user-sidebar/user-sidebar.component';
import { TeacherSidebarComponent } from './_components/sidebars/teacher-sidebar/teacher-sidebar.component';

import { SeparatorComponent } from './_components/other/separator/separator.component';

import { LearnMoreDialogComponent } from './_components/dialogs/learn-more-dialog/learn-more-dialog.component';
import { AdditionDialogComponent } from './_components/dialogs/addition-dialog/addition-dialog.component';
import { SearchUsersDialogComponent } from './_components/dialogs/search-users-dialog/search-users-dialog.component';
import { SearchDialogsDialogComponent } from './_components/dialogs/search-dialogs-dialog/search-dialogs-dialog.component';
import { ProfileViewDialogComponent } from './_components/dialogs/profile-view-dialog/profile-view-dialog.component';
import { NewListCreateComponent } from './_components/dialogs/new-list-create/new-list-create.component';


import { AdditionColumnComponent } from './_components/columns/addition-column/addition-column.component';
import { MultiplicationColumnComponent } from './_components/columns/multiplication-column/multiplication-column.component';
import { DivisionColumnComponent } from './_components/columns/division-column/division-column.component';

import { StudentInfoComponent } from './_components/info/student-info/student-info.component';
import { TeacherInfoComponent } from './_components/info/teacher-info/teacher-info.component';
import { UsersListComponent } from './_components/dashboards/users-list/users-list.component';
import { ChatComponent } from './_components/dashboards/chat/chat.component';
import { ConnectedDevicesComponent } from './_components/dashboards/connected-devices/connected-devices.component';
import { MarksTableComponent } from './_components/dashboards/marks-table/marks-table.component';
import { ListsComponent } from './_components/dashboards/lists/lists.component';
import { EditProfileComponent } from './_components/dashboards/edit-profile/edit-profile.component';

import { MessagesOverviewComponent } from './_components/other/messages-overview/messages-overview.component';

import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
import { MobileKeyboardComponent } from './_components/pages/mobile-keyboard/mobile-keyboard.component';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BodyComponent,
    UserDashboardComponent,
    TeacherDashboardComponent,
    UserSidebarComponent,
    TeacherSidebarComponent,
    SeparatorComponent,
    IndexComponent,
    LearnMoreDialogComponent,
    WorkspaceComponent,
    AdditionColumnComponent,
    MultiplicationColumnComponent,
    DivisionColumnComponent,
    AdditionDialogComponent,
    StudentInfoComponent,
    TeacherInfoComponent,
    UsersListComponent,
    ChatComponent,
    ConnectedDevicesComponent,
    MarksTableComponent,
    ListsComponent,
    SearchUsersDialogComponent,
    SearchDialogsDialogComponent,
    MessagesOverviewComponent,
    ProfileViewDialogComponent,
    EditProfileComponent,
    NewListCreateComponent,
    MobileKeyboardComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    LearnMoreDialogComponent,
    AdditionDialogComponent,
    SearchUsersDialogComponent,
    SearchDialogsDialogComponent,
    ProfileViewDialogComponent,
    NewListCreateComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MdNativeDateModule,
    MdDatepickerModule,
    MdButtonToggleModule,
    MdListModule,
    MdSnackBarModule,
    MdSelectModule,
    MdCheckboxModule,
    MdDialogModule,
    MdProgressSpinnerModule,
    MdInputModule,
    MdGridListModule,
    MdTooltipModule,
    MdSidenavModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdMenuModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdToolbarModule,
    MdIconModule,
    MdTabsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    AuthenticationService,
    SocketService,
    MdNativeDateModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I think you need to take advantage of lazy loaded modules,

Comment: optimize your components, services by modules